# java 11 rmi NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, rmi

I updated my application to use Java 11 and I am getting the below error when trying to rebind an object over RMI. The application works fine on Java 8.

They say NoClassDefFoundError can occur from a class being missing in the class path or from an error from a static block.

The $Proxy0 class is apparently a class that is created at runtime, so it should not be in the class path, but I am wondering if the rmiregristy knows this.

I don’t see any static blocks of code that may be causing the problem.

Open to any suggestions.

```
2021-09-21 14:27:18,750 (3019) [main] WARN  org.ets.speechrater.pm.RPMServer [] - Unable to create RMI object Retrying
java.rmi.ServerError: Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.ets.speechrater.pm.$Proxy0
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:388) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:303) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:279) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:380) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:158) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi/java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177) ~[?:?]
        at org.ets.speechrater.pm.RPMServer.main(RPMServer.java:104) ~[SpeechServlet-classes.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.ets.speechrater.pm.$Proxy0
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor2.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lambda$newInstance$0(ObjectStreamClass.java:1097) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.newInstance(ObjectStreamClass.java:1105) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2180) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:493) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:451) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(RegistryImpl_Skel.java:154) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:468) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:298) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562) ~[?:?]
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]
```

```
package org.ets.speechrater.pm;

import java.io.File;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.lang.SecurityManager;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

import org.ets.research.srater.config.Config;
import org.ets.speechrater.properties.PropertiesAssist;
import org.ets.speechrater.util.ETSLogger;

/**
 * RPMServer
 * 
 * Operational wrapper for RPMImpl, which implements the speech recognition
 * (server) components.
 * 
 * 
 * 
 */
public class RPMServer { // class RPMServer

    static private ETSLogger logger = ETSLogger.getLogger(RPMServer.class
            .getName());

    static RPM rpm;

    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // main()
    //
    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Throwable { // main()

        try {

            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());

            String propertyKey = null;
            String bindingName;
            int portNumber;
            String rmiAddr;
            int hostIndex = 0;
            boolean rpmSimMode = false;

            try { // get access to the logger
                PropertiesAssist.initPmProperty(args[0]);
            } // get access to the logger
            catch (Exception e) {
                String msg = "Unable to load properties";
                logger.error(msg);
                throw new RemoteException(msg, e);
            }
            
            try {
                if (args.length > 1)
                    hostIndex = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                else
                    hostIndex = 0;

                propertyKey = "rpm" + hostIndex + "BindingName";
                logger.debug("propertyKey " + propertyKey);

                bindingName = PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString(propertyKey);
                propertyKey = "rpm" + hostIndex + "Port";
                logger.debug("propertyKey " + propertyKey);
                portNumber = Integer.parseInt(PropertiesAssist
                        .getPmPropertyString(propertyKey));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                String msg = "Unable to get bindingName or port property. "
                        + propertyKey;
                logger.error(msg);

                throw new RemoteException(msg, e);
            }
            try {
                propertyKey = "rpmRMIAddr";
                rmiAddr = PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString(propertyKey);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                rmiAddr = null;
            }

            if (args.length > 2) {
                rpmSimMode = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[2]);
                logger.debug("rpmSimMode is " + rpmSimMode);
            }

            rpm = null;
            while (rpm == null) { // Retry until have reference
                try {
                    logger.debug("In server before Object rpm");
                    if (!rpmSimMode)
                        rpm = new RPMImpl(logger, portNumber);
                    else
                        rpm = new RPMImplSim(logger, portNumber);

                    logger.debug("RPM Implementation: " + rpm);
                    logger.debug("In server after Object rpm");
                    if (rmiAddr != null)
                        bindingName = rmiAddr + "/" + bindingName;

                    logger.debug("In server binding to " + bindingName);
                    Naming.rebind(bindingName, rpm);
                    logger.debug("In server after bind rpm to tagRPM");
                } catch (Exception e) { // catch block
                    logger.warn("Unable to create RMI object Retrying",e);
                    String msg = "Is rmiregistry running?";
                    logger.warn(msg);
                    logger.debug(e);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } // catch block
            } // Retry until have reference

            final String killFilename = PropertiesAssist
                    .getPmPropertyString("killFile.server");
            if (killFilename == null || killFilename.length() == 0) {
                logger.warn("Property not found: killFile.server");
            } else {
                final String finalBindingName = bindingName;
                Runnable killFileWatcher = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        File f = new File(killFilename);
                        while (f == null || !f.exists()) {
                            f = new File(killFilename);
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(5000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            }
                        }

                        if (f.exists()) {
                            logger.info("Kill file found. Stopping server");
                            try {
                                rpm.shutdown();
                                logger.info("All recognizer instances shut down successfully.");
                                Naming.unbind(finalBindingName);
                                rpm = null;
                                logger.info("(Server) Bye.");
                                System.exit(0);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                killFileWatcher.run();
            }
            logger.debug("RPMServer: End of main().");

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            logger.fatal("RPMServer: Throwable Exception caught " + t.toString(), t);

            throw t;
        }
    } // main()
} // class RPMServer
```

```
package org.ets.speechrater.pm;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.ets.research.srater.exceptions.RecognizerException;
import org.ets.research.srater.asrfa.FeatureExtractionPipeline;
import org.ets.research.srater.kaldi.KaldiPipeline;
import org.ets.research.srater.htk.HtkPipeline;
import org.ets.research.srater.config.Config;
import org.ets.research.srater.config.ConfigFactory;
import org.ets.research.srater.scoring.CTMData;
import org.ets.research.srater.scoring.SpeechSample;
import org.ets.research.srater.util.Tools;
import org.ets.research.srater.util.os.DirectoryHandler;
import org.ets.speechrater.ScoringRequest;
import org.ets.speechrater.properties.PropertiesAssist;
import org.ets.speechrater.util.ETSLogger;

//######################################################################
//
// class RPMImpl   implements RPM
//
// This object provides a very thin layer between a remote client
//    and a list of local Recognizers.
//
// Errors:
//    A message will be displayed
//       All messages coming from this class will begin with RPM
//    A trace of the trapped exception will be displayed
//    A remote exception will be thrown including the displayed
//       message and the text of the trapped exception.
//
// Errors: all throw RemoteException
//
// Client calls LPMRecognizer.extract()
// LPMRecognizer.extract() calls RPM.extract()
// RPM.extract() calls KaldiPipeline.extract()
//
//######################################################################

public class RPMImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements RPM { // class
                                                                    // RPMImpl

    static ETSLogger loggerPm;

    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // private vars
    //
    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 271828182845904523L;

    private Map<String,FeatureExtractionPipeline[]> _RecognizerList;
    private boolean[] busyFlags;

    private int _numEVRecognizer;
    private String _msg; // last error. Keep

    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // RPMImpl() constructor
    //
    // Construct an object as an rmi remote target.
    //
    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public RPMImpl(ETSLogger logger, int port) throws RemoteException { // RPMImpl()
                                                                        // constructor
        super(port); // Set the port
        _msg = "";
        loggerPm = logger;
        loggerPm.debug("RPMImpl constructed.");
    } // RPMImpl() constructor

    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // init()
    //
    // instantiate a list of MultimodalRecognizer objects.
    // instantiate a list of EV Recognizer objects.
    //
    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void init(int inNumEVRecognizer) throws Exception { // init()
        Config configTPO = ConfigFactory.makeConfig(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.tpo.config.name"));  //note it does not matter what config is used, because just basic things are used (e.g. basedir...)
        configTPO.load(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.master.config"));
        Config configNEWORIENTAL = ConfigFactory.makeConfig(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.neworiental.config.name"));  //note it does not matter what config is used, because just basic things are used (e.g. basedir...)
        configNEWORIENTAL.load(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.master.config"));
        Config configTOEFLIBT = ConfigFactory.makeConfig(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.toeflibt.config"));
        configTOEFLIBT.load(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.master.config"));
        
        _numEVRecognizer = inNumEVRecognizer;

        if (PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("Srater.recognizerType")
                .toUpperCase().equals("KALDI")) {
            _RecognizerList = new HashMap<String,FeatureExtractionPipeline[]>();
            _RecognizerList.put(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.tpo.config.name"),new KaldiPipeline[_numEVRecognizer]);
            _RecognizerList.put(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.neworiental.config.name"),new KaldiPipeline[_numEVRecognizer]);
            _RecognizerList.put(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.toeflibt.config"),new KaldiPipeline[_numEVRecognizer]);
            
            loggerPm.debug("HTK Array initiaized");
        } else if (PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("Srater.recognizerType")
                .toUpperCase().equals("HTK")) {
            _RecognizerList = new HashMap<String,FeatureExtractionPipeline[]>();
            _RecognizerList.put(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.tpo.config.name"),new HtkPipeline[_numEVRecognizer]);
            _RecognizerList.put(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.neworiental.config.name"),new HtkPipeline[_numEVRecognizer]);
            _RecognizerList.put(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.toeflibt.config"),new HtkPipeline[_numEVRecognizer]);
            loggerPm.debug("HTK Array initiaized");
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Srater.recognizerType set to unknown type: "
                    + PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString(
                            "Srater.recognizerType").toUpperCase());
        }

        busyFlags = new boolean[_numEVRecognizer];

        loggerPm.debug("Ready to create " + _numEVRecognizer + " EVRecognizer");

        // Chi added
        String outputDirName = null;

        try {
            outputDirName = PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("Srater.outputDirName");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            _msg = "Unable to get property MultimodalRecognizer arg";
            loggerPm.error(_msg, e);
            throw new RemoteException(_msg, e);
        }

        loggerPm.debug("Ready to create " + _numEVRecognizer + " EVRecognizer");
        for (int index = 0; index < _numEVRecognizer; index++) {
            try {
                if (PropertiesAssist
                        .getPmPropertyString("Srater.recognizerType")
                        .toUpperCase().equals("KALDI")) {
                    try {
                        _RecognizerList.get(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.tpo.config.name"))[index] = new KaldiPipeline(configTPO);
                        _RecognizerList.get(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.neworiental.config.name"))[index] = new KaldiPipeline(configNEWORIENTAL);
                        _RecognizerList.get(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.toeflibt.config"))[index] = new KaldiPipeline(configTOEFLIBT);
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        loggerPm.error("some type of error with recognizer" + e.getMessage());
                        
                        if (e instanceof RecognizerException) {
                            throw new RecognizerException(new Exception(e.getMessage()));
                        }
                        else{
                            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
                        }
                        
                    }
                            //outputDirName,
                            //"",                           //note that archiving of dat and ctm are handled outside of extract now
                            //config);
                    loggerPm.debug("HTK Array[" + index + "] initiaized");
                } else if (PropertiesAssist
                        .getPmPropertyString("Srater.recognizerType")
                        .toUpperCase().equals("HTK")) {
                    try {
                        _RecognizerList.get("research.tpo.config.name")[index] = new HtkPipeline(configTPO);
                        _RecognizerList.get("research.neworiental.config.name")[index] = new HtkPipeline(configNEWORIENTAL);
                        _RecognizerList.get("research.toeflibt.config")[index] = new HtkPipeline(configTOEFLIBT);
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        loggerPm.error("some type of error with recognizer" + e.getMessage());
                        
                        if (e instanceof RecognizerException) {
                            throw new RecognizerException(new Exception(e.getMessage()));
                        }
                        else{
                            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                            //outputDirName,
                            //"",                           //note that archiving of dat and ctm are handled outside of extract now
                            //config);
                    loggerPm.debug("HTK Array[" + index + "] initiaized");
                } else {
                    throw new Exception(
                            "Srater.recognizerType set to unknown type: "
                                    + PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString(
                                            "Srater.recognizerType")
                                            .toUpperCase());
                }

                busyFlags[index] = false;
                loggerPm.debug("MultimodalRecognizer " + index + " Created");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                _msg = "RPM init failed";
                loggerPm.error(_msg, e);
                throw new RemoteException(_msg, e);
            }
        }
    } // init()



    /***
     * Note this saves TPO *.ctm and *.dat to files.
     *
     * @param ctm
     * @throws Exception
     *
     */
    public void generateDatFromCTMandArchiveDATandCTM(CTMData ctm, String fileName) throws Exception {
        String archiveFilenamePathAndPrefix = new File(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("Srater.dataWarehouseDir"),fileName).getAbsolutePath();

        //create dat file
        File outFile = new File(archiveFilenamePathAndPrefix + ".dat");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outFile));
        pw.print(ctm.PfHeader());
        pw.print(ctm.getFeatureStr());
        pw.close();

        //create ctm file
        outFile = new File(archiveFilenamePathAndPrefix + ".ctm");
        pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outFile));
        pw.print(ctm.getCtm());
//      pw.print(ctm.PfHeader());
//      pw.print(ctm.getFeatureStr());
        pw.close();

    }







    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // extract()
    //
    // call the specified MultimodalRecognizer in the object list.
    //
    // Client calls LPMRecognizer.extract()
    // LPMRecognizer.extract() calls RPM.extract()
    // RPM.extract() calls KaldiPipeline.extract()
    //
    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // public CTM extract( int index, SpeechSample toServ ) throws
    // RemoteException, RecognizerException
    // { // extract()

    public CTMData extract(
            int index,
            SpeechSample toServ,
            ScoringRequest scoringRequest,
            String modelName,
            String configName,
            String masterConfigFileName
            ) throws RemoteException,
            RecognizerException { // extract()
        String ID = toServ.getID();
        loggerPm.debug("RPM Ready to extract Thread " + index + "  DB " + ID);
        boolean saveTmpOnFailure = true;
        DirectoryHandler workingDirHandler = null;

        try {
            busyFlags[index] = true;

            Config config = ConfigFactory.makeConfig(configName);
            config.load(masterConfigFileName);
            loggerPm.warn("masterConfig>>>>:"+masterConfigFileName);

            try{
                saveTmpOnFailure = PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("Srater.saveTempDirOnExtractFailure").equals("true");
            } catch (Exception any) {};


            //TPOv5 version of extract
            String baseDir = PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("tmpPath");
            String dirPrefix = "recognizer_" + scoringRequest.getRequestID().getRequestID().toString() + "_";
//          String workingDir = new File(baseDir, dirPrefix).getAbsolutePath() + index;
            workingDirHandler = new DirectoryHandler(baseDir, dirPrefix);


            CTMData ctm = null;

            //save sound file to disk before extract
            String filenameWithExtension = new File(workingDirHandler.getWorkingDir(), toServ.getID() + "." + toServ.getSampleCodec()).getAbsolutePath() ;
            toServ.saveFile(filenameWithExtension);
            if (PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("Srater.recognizerType")
                    .toUpperCase().equals("KALDI")) {
                ctm = ((KaldiPipeline)_RecognizerList.get(configName)[index]).extract(toServ, workingDirHandler);
            }
            else if (PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("Srater.recognizerType")
                    .toUpperCase().equals("HTK")) {
                ctm = ((HtkPipeline)_RecognizerList.get(configName)[index]).extract(toServ, workingDirHandler);
            }

            ctm.SetSampleID(toServ.getID());
//          generateCdatFromCTM();

            //create dat and ctm files and archive them
            // !!! adding proper file name as a parameter
            generateDatFromCTMandArchiveDATandCTM(ctm,
                    scoringRequest.getRequestID()+"-"+scoringRequest.getClientRequestID());

            //clean up directory
            if(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("Srater.deleteTempfiles").equals("true")){
                workingDirHandler.deleteWorkingDir();
                
            }
            else{
                loggerPm.debug("not deleting temporary files for: " + scoringRequest.getRequestID().getRequestID().toString() + " , directory: " + workingDirHandler.getWorkingDir().toPath().toAbsolutePath().toString());
            }



//          CTMData ctm = _RecognizerList[index].extract(
//                  toServ,
//                  PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("Srater.deleteOutputfiles").equals("true"),
//                  PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("Srater.deleteTempfiles").equals("true"),
//                  scoringRequest.getRequestID() + "-"+ scoringRequest.getClientRequestID(),
//                  modelName
//                  ,config
//
//          );

            loggerPm.debug("Extract Features Header:" + ctm.PfHeader());
//          loggerPm.debug("Extract Features Values:"
//                  + ctm.PfOutput(""));
            loggerPm.debug("Extract Features Names and Values:"
                    + ctm.getFeatureStr());



            loggerPm.debug("RPM Done extract Thread " + index + "  DB " + ID);
            return (ctm);

        } catch (RecognizerException e) {
            _msg = "RPM extract caught RecognizerException (" + e.getMessage()
                    + ") Thread " + index + "  DB " + ID;
            loggerPm.warn(_msg, e);

            try{
                if(!saveTmpOnFailure && workingDirHandler != null)
                    workingDirHandler.deleteWorkingDir();
            }catch(Exception any){}

            throw e;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            _msg = "RPM extract failed Thread " + index + "  DB " + ID;
            loggerPm.warn(_msg + t.toString(), t);
            throw new RemoteException(_msg, t);
        }

    } // extract()

    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // refresh()
    //
    // One of the recognizers has failed.
    // This method replaces the broken object with a new one.
    //
    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void refresh(int index) throws RemoteException { // refresh()


        // Chi added
        String outputDirName = null;

        try {

            outputDirName = PropertiesAssist
                    .getPmPropertyString("Srater.outputDirName");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            _msg = "Unable to get property MultimodalRecognizer arg";
            loggerPm.error(_msg, e);
            throw new RemoteException(_msg, e);
        }
        try {
//          Config.readMasterConfig(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.master.config"));
//          Config.setCurrentConfig(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.tpo.config.name"));
            Config configTPO = ConfigFactory.makeConfig(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.tpo.config.name"));  //note it does not matter what config is used, because just basic things are used (e.g. basedir...)
            configTPO.load(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.master.config"));
            Config configNEWORIENTAL = ConfigFactory.makeConfig(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.neworiental.config.name"));  //note it does not matter what config is used, because just basic things are used (e.g. basedir...)
            configNEWORIENTAL.load(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.master.config"));
            Config configTOEFLIBT = ConfigFactory.makeConfig(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.toeflibt.config"));
            configTOEFLIBT.load(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.master.config"));


            if (PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("Srater.recognizerType")
                    .toUpperCase().equals("HTK")) {
                try {
                    _RecognizerList.get(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.tpo.config.name")))[index] = new HtkPipeline(configTPO);
                    _RecognizerList.get(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.neworiental.config.name")))[index] = new HtkPipeline(configNEWORIENTAL);                    
                    _RecognizerList.get(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.toeflibt.config")))[index] = new HtkPipeline(configTOEFLIBT);                   
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    loggerPm.error("some type of error with recognizer" + e.getMessage());
                    
                    if (e instanceof RecognizerException) {
                        throw new RecognizerException(new Exception(e.getMessage()));
                    }
                    else{
                        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                        //outputDirName,
                        //"",                           //note that archiving of dat and ctm are handled outside of extract now
                        //config);
                loggerPm.debug("HTK Array[" + index + "] refreshed");
            } else if (PropertiesAssist
                    .getPmPropertyString("Srater.recognizerType").toUpperCase()
                    .equals("KALDI")) {
                try {
                    _RecognizerList.get(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.tpo.config.name"))[index] = new KaldiPipeline(configTPO);
                    _RecognizerList.get(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.neworiental.config.name"))[index] = new KaldiPipeline(configNEWORIENTAL);
                    _RecognizerList.get(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.toeflibt.config"))[index] = new KaldiPipeline(configTOEFLIBT);
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    loggerPm.error("some type of error with recognizer" + e.getMessage());
                    
                    if (e instanceof RecognizerException) {
                        throw new RecognizerException(new Exception(e.getMessage()));
                    }
                    else{
                        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                        //outputDirName,
                        //"",                           //note that archiving of dat and ctm are handled outside of extract now
                        //config);
                loggerPm.debug("KALDI Array[" + index + "] refreshed");

            } else {
                throw new Exception(
                        "Srater.recognizerType set to unknown type: "
                                + PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString(
                                        "Srater.recognizerType").toUpperCase());
            }


            loggerPm.debug("MultimodalRecognizer " + index + " Refreshed");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            _msg = "RPM refresh failed";
            loggerPm.error(_msg, e);
            throw new RemoteException(_msg, e);
        }

    } // refresh()

    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // pingRemote()
    //
    // Recovery has been attempted.
    // A reference has been acquired.
    // But is it a stale one that is still in the registry.
    // This method is used to validate.
    // If the reference is stale a remote exception is thrown.
    // If not stale "OK"
    //
    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public String pingRemote() throws RemoteException { // pingRemote()
        return ("OK");
    } // pingRemote()



    public void shutdown() {

        for (int i = 0; i < _numEVRecognizer; i++) {
            int retryCount = 0;
            while (busyFlags[i] && retryCount < 60) {
                loggerPm.debug("Recognizer " + (i + 1) + " is busy.");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                retryCount++;
            }
            loggerPm.info("Shutting down recognizer instance " + (i + 1) + ".");

            try {
                _RecognizerList.get(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.tpo.config.name"))[i].close();
                _RecognizerList.get(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.neworiental.config.name"))[i].close();
                _RecognizerList.get(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.toeflibt.config"))[i].close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                loggerPm.warn("Recognizer close (which removes the temporary directory used for that instance) - failed",e);
            }

            try {
                _RecognizerList.get(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.tpo.config.name"))[i] = null;
                _RecognizerList.get(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.neworiental.config.name"))[i] = null;
                _RecognizerList.get(PropertiesAssist.getPmPropertyString("research.toeflibt.config"))[i] = null;                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                loggerPm.warn("ignoring error when setting recognizer to null, because we are shutting down already");
            }
        }
        loggerPm.info("All recognizers have been shut down.");
    }

    public void setBusy(int index, boolean busy) throws RemoteException {
        loggerPm.debug("RPM recognizer(" + index + ") is "
                + (busy ? "" : "no longer ") + "busy.");
        busyFlags[index] = busy;
    }

} // class RPMImpl
```

Comment: You must ensure yourself that the necessary classes are present on the remote end. RMI doesn’t copy them for you.

Comment: I added the code to the question, it fails on the Naming.rebind call.  The application and RMI Registry are running Java 11.  They have the same CLASSPATH.

Comment: If you're using an external JAR or something like that, you have to include it in your classpath when you compile/run it. Through your errors, it looks like it's having trouble accessing classes from something like a dependency or external libraries. Might want to check your classpath when you compile/run it. (Only if you're using external lib/jar. I'm assuming you are?) If not, then it would have something to do with running it where it can't access the class either through some kind of "wrong access" etc.

Comment: not sure what an external JAR is, but I am using jars in my CLASSPATH.  All of the jars are there and are accessible, otherwise the application would not have worked in Java 8.

Comment: Is there another exception further down under the line `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.ets.speechrater.pm.$Proxy0`? The Registry does need access to the same classpath as the server. You could try running it within the same JVM via `LocateRegsisry.createRegistry()`.

Comment: There are no other exceptions. I was able to create a simple example of an RMI job that works on Java 8 and not 11 and has a similar error. I posted that as a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69305196/java-11-rmi-seems-to-be-broken-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror . You should be able replicate the problem by trying the code there.

Comment: well, thanks for your help.

Comment: The RMI Registry doesn't have access via its CLASSPATH to your application's remote interfaces and whatever else in your application they depend on.

Answer (score 0):

If I use the rmiregistry executable that comes with the JDK, I have this problem.  But using code to create the registry seems to be a good work around.

```
package org.ets.speechrater.util;

import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class RMIregistry {
    static ETSLogger logger = ETSLogger.getLogger(RMIregistry.class
            .getName());
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Integer.valueOf(args[0]));
            
            logger.info("Server ready");
            
            while(true) {
                TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1000);
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Server exception: " + e.toString(),e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The RMI Registry doesn't have access via its CLASSPATH to your application's remote interfaces and whatever else in your application they depend on. Starting the Registry this way fixes that.

Answer (score -1):

try to add modules (include the NoClassDefFoundError classes) to rmiregistry like:

```
rmiregistry -J--add-modules=java.sql
```

Comment: What does `java.sql` have to do with it?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not unclear, just irrelevant. There is no mention of `java.sql` anywhere in the question.